# Permalink Setting Changes From Post Name to Default After Changing The Page Name

Tags: theme-development, permalinks

I had to change a page name through theme folder like

/`currentTheme/ page-eyeglasses.php to ---> page-eyeglasses-1.php`

to make the page not temporarily not accessible. But after returning the file name to original name `page-eyeglasses.php` while the page still is in the theme but I am getting `URL Not Found`

I figure it out this is happening because the permalink changes from `Post name` name to `default` every time that I change the name of the `page-eyeglasses.php`

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can prevent this to keep always the Permalink setting on Post name?

Comment: It seems unlikely that the permalink of a post would change when you rename a template file. Can you provide more information about the issue?

Comment: Thanks Mike but all things are simple as this! I change a name of page template explicitly and the prtmalink setting also change!

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something then, because a filesystem change to template files shouldn't be changing a permaliink. it doesn't work that way. Are you running any kind of plugins that manage template files?